# Magento 2: Overwrite Block file of Magento Module

Tags: magento2

I want to overwrite some lines in

> */vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/AuthorizationLink.php*

How can I do this? I appreciate any help =)

Answer (score 3):

you should try to use a plugin for this. With Plugins you can manipulate the parameters, return values, or both of any public function of any Object loaded by the Magento object Manager

Alan Storm wrote [a pretty nice Article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system) about the Plugin System:

**===UPDATE===**

If you do not succeed with using plugins, you can actually change the preference in di configuration and replace the block.

More on that [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences).

still, Plugins and Observers should always be your first choice

Answer (score 0):

**I override some lines in the "vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink.php".**

**step 1**
**So I created a extension structure "app/code/Sample/Mycode":
/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 harsh shah
*/
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" type="Sample\Mycode\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" /

</config>
```

**step 2
create AuthorizationLink.php 
/Block/Account/AuthorizationLink.php**

```
<?php

namespace Sample\Mycode\Block;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Hello World') : __('Hello World 2');
    }
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```